# Header not showing but footer is in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, css, header, footer, master-pages

I have not had much experience working with the site.master or site.css before, so i do not know where  am going wrong.

I have set a footer and a header in my applicaiton, in the design view everything shows up fine. But when i debug it in local, the header does not show; whereas the footer does.

Can anyone help me.

Thanks!

html:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
 <head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <link href="~/Styles/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="HeadContent" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
<body>
<form id="Form1" runat="server">
<div class="page">
    <div class="header">
        <div class="title">
            <h1>
                My ASP.NET Application
            </h1>
        </div>
        <div class="loginDisplay">
            <asp:LoginView ID="HeadLoginView" runat="server" EnableViewState="false">
                <AnonymousTemplate>
                    [ <a href="~/Account/Login.aspx" ID="HeadLoginStatus" runat="server">Log In</a> ]
                </AnonymousTemplate>
                <LoggedInTemplate>
                    Welcome <span class="bold"><asp:LoginName ID="HeadLoginName" runat="server" /></span>!
                    [ <asp:LoginStatus ID="HeadLoginStatus" runat="server" LogoutAction="Redirect" LogoutText="Log Out" LogoutPageUrl="~/"/> ]
                </LoggedInTemplate>
            </asp:LoginView>
        </div>
        <div class="clear hideSkiplink">
            <asp:Menu ID="NavigationMenu" runat="server" CssClass="menu" EnableViewState="false" IncludeStyleBlock="false" Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Items>
                    <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Default.aspx" Text="Home"/>
                    <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/About.aspx" Text="About"/>
                </Items>
            </asp:Menu>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="main">
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server"/>
    </div>
    <div class="clear">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="footer" style="clear: both; text-align:center ; padding: 30px; background-color:Olive; border: 0px solid #DBDDDE; color:White ">
    Copyright 2013 IndieRevo
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Output:

```
 Line 1: error: expected identifier or '(' before '{' token
 Line 1: error: stray '@' in program
 Line 3: error: expected identifier or '(' before '<' token
```

Site.css:

http://codepad.org/vcCs4AN9

css:

```
body   
{
background: #b6b7bc;
font-size: .80em;
font-family: "Helvetica Neue", "Lucida Grande", "Segoe UI", Arial, Helvetica, Verdana, sans-serif;
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
color: #696969;
}

a:link, a:visited
{
color: #034af3;
}

a:hover
{
color: #1d60ff;
text-decoration: none;
}

a:active
{
color: #034af3;
}

p
{
margin-bottom: 10px;
line-height: 1.6em;
}
```

/* HEADINGS
----------------------------------------------------------*/

```
  h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6
{
font-size: 1.5em;
color: #666666;
font-variant: small-caps;
text-transform: none;
font-weight: 200;
margin-bottom: 0px;    
background-image: url('/Images/utensilsheader.png');
}

test
{
background-image: url(../images/1.png);
position: relative;
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;


width: auto;
height: 255px;
top: 0px;
left: 1px;
}

h1
{
font-size: 1.6em;
padding-bottom: 0px;
margin-bottom: 0px;

background-image: url('/Images/utensilsheader.png');
}

h2
{
font-size: 1.5em;
font-weight: 600;

background-image: url('/Images/utensilsheader.png');
}

h3
{
font-size: 1.2em;

background-image: url('/Images/utensilsheader.png');
}

h4
{
font-size: 1.1em;

background-image: url('/Images/utensilsheader.png');
}

h5, h6
```

{
    font-size: 1em;

```
background-image: url('/Images/utensilsheader.png');
}
```

/* this rule styles  and  tags that are the 
first child of the left and right table columns */

```
 .rightColumn > h1, .rightColumn > h2, .leftColumn > h1, .leftColumn > h2
{
margin-top: 0px;
}
```

/* PRIMARY LAYOUT ELEMENTS
----------------------------------------------------------*/

```
 .page
{
width: 1080px;
background-color: White;
margin: 20px auto 0px auto;
border: 1px solid #496077;
}

.header
{
position: relative;
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
background-image: url('/Images/utensilsheader.png');

width: auto;
height: 255px;
top: 0px;
left: 1px;
}

.header h1
{
font-weight: 700;
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px 0px 0px 20px;
color: #f9f9f9;
border: none;
line-height: 2em;
font-size: 2em;
```

}

```
.main
{
padding: 0px 12px;
margin: 12px 8px 8px 8px;
min-height: 420px;
}

 .leftCol
{
padding: 6px 0px;
margin: 12px 8px 8px 8px;
width: 200px;
min-height: 200px;
}

.footer
{
color: #4e5766;
padding: 8px 0px 0px 0px;
margin: 0px auto;
text-align: center;
line-height: normal;


 }
```

/* TAB MENU
----------------------------------------------------------*/

```
 div.hideSkiplink
{
background-color:#3a4f63;
width:100%;
display:none;

 }

 div.menu
{
padding: 4px 0px 4px 8px;
display:none;

}

div.menu ul
{
list-style: none;
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
width: auto;

}

div.menu ul li a, div.menu ul li a:visited
{
background-color: White;
border: 1px #4e667d solid;
color: #dde4ec;
display: block;
line-height: 1.35em;
padding: 4px 20px;
text-decoration: none;
white-space: nowrap;

}

div.menu ul li a:hover
{
background-color: #bfcbd6;
color: #465c71;
text-decoration: none;

}

div.menu ul li a:active
{
background-color: #465c71;
color: #cfdbe6;
text-decoration: none;

}
```

/* FORM ELEMENTS
----------------------------------------------------------*/

```
fieldset
{
margin: 1em 0px;
padding: 1em;
border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

fieldset p 
{
margin: 2px 12px 10px 10px;
 }

fieldset.login label, fieldset.register label, fieldset.changePassword label
{
display: block;
 }

fieldset label.inline 
{
display: inline;
}

legend 
{
font-size: 1.1em;
font-weight: 600;
padding: 2px 4px 8px 4px;
}

input.textEntry 
{
width: 320px;
border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

input.passwordEntry 
{
width: 320px;
border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

div.accountInfo
{
width: 42%;
}
```

/* MISC
----------------------------------------------------------*/

```
.clear
{
clear: both;
}

.title
{
display: none;
float: left;
text-align: left;
width: auto;
}

.loginDisplay
{
font-size: 1.1em;
display: block;
text-align: right;
padding: 10px;
color: White;
}

.loginDisplay a:link
{
color: white;
 }

.loginDisplay a:visited
{
color: white;
}

 .loginDisplay a:hover
{
color: white;
}

.failureNotification
{
font-size: 1.2em;
color: Red;
 }

.bold
{
font-weight: bold;
}

 .submitButton
{
text-align: right;
padding-right: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Does it happen in all browsers or a specific browser? You need to narrow down the scope. Remove everything in css and add back one line at a time.

Comment: Hi, how do i get it to run in a different browser? i have internet explorer currently set?

Comment: Copy the http://localhost:xxx/Default.aspx from IE and past it to FireFox, Chrome and Safari

Comment: Ah breakthrough! It works on chrome, but not internet explorer?

Comment: Welcome to IE world. ;) Some of your css are not compatible with IE.

Comment: Ah i see, well thats a kick in the teeth. What would you recommend me do? Only limit the users to view the website on chrome, safari etc?...

Comment: It is easy to fix it; it is just a second nature of web developer :D As I said, remove everything inside css, and re-add it back one line at a time.

Comment: If you can't find the bug, copy your html source/view source to codepad. We might be able to find it for you.

Comment: All of the code i am using for it, is situated above. i cant seem to find the error as of yet. But for now i am going to debug it in chrome, until i get a result i am happy with. And then i am going to look at IE error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one of the bugs - h1 color is White. It's why you cannot see it in white background.

Here is how you debug in browser. FireFox has FireBug.

I hope this will help you keep going.

Debug in IE
[image]

Debug In Chrome
[image]

Comment: hmmmm, the problem is that i cant see the image in the header when i run it in IE. When i go to the background image, it says none next to it. Even though i have set ne in the css?

Comment: And thanks for the info on debugging, it has helped as this is an easier way of seeing what is going on.

Comment: Great. If this answers your question, please make it as answered. It'll help the community.